# Binary to csv Parser design

Tags: c++, c, csv, parsing, binary-data

The aim is to make a binary to csv parser.
I have a binary file containing command/response packets from a micro-controller. Around 30-40 command types are there.The structure of the command packets are different. To know the type of the command, you have to see the first few bits which are the command type. With this command type you have to identify the structure of the commands (which should show what individual fields  in the packet mean and how to convert these fields to csv data like int, char, string and sometimes some specific functions to process some fields and then convert).

I have a reader thread and writer thread already running which copies the binary data from disk to an input buffer and from an output buffer to the disk as csv file. I have to design an intermediate parser thread which takes in the binary data from the input buffer and convert it into csv and push it to the output buffer.

The coding has to be done in C/C++ (preferably C) and performance is a top priority. I am looking for an architecture for this parser from the view of how to store these command type structures and how to access and parse the data according to this fast.3rd party software which can do this fast is also ok.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you could have a base class that models the common fields of the command, then have each command inherit from the base.  Search the internet for "c++ factory design pattern".

Comment: Thank you so much for this info on factory design pattern. In C for the table of commands, which data strucutre do you think will be best suited ?

Comment: I use a table of structures.  This allows the compiler to store them into read-only memory and the data is available before `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C++, you could use `std::map` and associate the command value with a function pointer (or function object) that processes the command.

In C (and C++), you can use a table of commands and function pointers.  Search the table for the command then execute the associated function by dereferencing the function pointer.  For large command sets, you can use `upper_bound` or `lower_bound` to find the command (for small data sets, linear search has better performance).  You can store the table in read-only memory.